# Is it possible to drop duplicates of only one (or a few) specific row(s)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of rows describing actions associated with users, and I want to keep only the earliest example of each user's action, but I only want to this for certain users. Practically this means dropping duplicates based on all columns except the user ID column and the action identifier, and keeping the first, but doing it for only certain users is difficult to me.

The closest I've come is using a groupby to group rows by user and action (essentially finding the duplicates), taking the .first() of each group, and then filtering that frame to get the first action only for the users that I wanted, but then I had problems rejoining this data to the rest of the data. The only way I can think of doing this would involve dropping all the rows that match values in the columns of the first action rows, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Example input/output:

Input:

| User ID | Action ID | Date | Other Columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | asdf | 2021/1/1 | ... |
| 1234 | asdf | 2021/1/2 | ... |
| 1234 | hjkl | 2021/1/1 | ... |
| 1234 | hjkl | 2021/1/2 | ... |
| 0987 | asdf | 2021/1/1 | ... |
| 0987 | asdf | 2021/1/2 | ... |
| 5363 | asdf | 2021/1/2 | ... |

Then say I want to get only each earliest action for User ID 1234. I want:

| User ID | Action ID | Date | Other Columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | asdf | 2021/1/1 | ... |
| 1234 | hjkl | 2021/1/1 | ... |
| 0987 | asdf | 2021/1/1 | ... |
| 0987 | asdf | 2021/1/2 | ... |
| 5363 | asdf | 2021/1/2 | ... |

For this example, I am considering only the User ID and Action ID columns for finding the duplicates.

Comment: Can you show an example of the data and the expected output?

Comment: @Ashyam I added an example in the post, hope it helps.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first filter by the User IDs by using `isin()` from pandas,

```
filter_df = df[df["user_id"].isin([1,3])]
```

You can then group by the User IDs and the Action IDs and keep the first one from these,

```
filter_df = filter_df.groupby(['user_id', 'action_id']).first()
```

You will need to reset the `filter_df` index before concatenating it back with the original dataframe,

```
filter_df = filter_df.reset_index()
```

In order to join the `filter_df` values back to the original dataframe you can first drop all rows from the original dataframe that match both the User ID and the Action ID from the `filter_df`,

```
rec = filter_df[["User ID", "Action ID"]].to_records(index=False) 

df= df[~df[["User ID", "Action ID"]].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(rec)]
```

Then the `filter_df` can simply be concatenated to the original dataframe,

```
df = pd.concat([df, filter_df], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I have right now. However, I want to be able to join these first rows back into the original dataframe, creating a frame where just the duplicates of the specific columns are dropped. I think I would need to drop all rows that match both the specific User ID's and Action ID's SIMULTANEOUSLY, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: The above answer has been updated to include how to join the filter dataframe back to the original dataframe with duplicates dropped.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but your answer only checks that each value occurs in a duplicated row individually, not simultaneously (i.e. they occur together in the same row). I ended up casting the rows to tuples and then using isin() to check that they occurred together. It works, but seems inefficient, so I'm still open to improvements.

Comment: Apparently I can't edit your comment but I replaced your line where you dropped the lines with: `rec = filter_df[["User ID", "Action ID"]].to_records(index=False)`
`df= df[~df[["User ID", "Action ID"]].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(rec)]`

Comment: I added an edit with the way I did it. I also didn't reset_index(), but I suppose it may or may not be useful, depending on the situation.